# Obtaining the windows desktop path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LPTSTR myPath = NULL;

    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, myPath, CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);

    if(myPath != NULL)
        cout << "It returns something" << endl;
    else
        cout << "It returns nothing" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

But myPath returns nothing. I just want to obtain the Desktop path. I'm on Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give it room to put the data into:

```
T_CHAR myPath[ MAX_PATH ];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, myPath, CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't work with the windows api, so It's my first time. What's the difference between T_CHAR and LPTSTR? LPTSTR can't receive an output from the system call? Thank you!

Comment: LPTSTR is a pointer, and in your code it's pointing to nothing. You need to pass the function a buffer (a chunk of memory) that it can store the string in.

Comment: `LPTSTR` is a pointer to a `TCHAR`.  You should be using `TCHAR` instead of `T_CHAR`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, miss-typed TCHAR.